# How can I randomly access my list elements by a percentage?

Tags: c#, image

I have a list of points which are holding the coordinates (x,y) of the black pixels in my image.

```
List<Point> blackPixels = new List<Point>();
```

Does nay one know how I can randomly change the colour of the black pixels to white by a specific percentage? i.e. to turn 80% of the black pixels to white? many thanks

Comment: change `blackPixels.Count * 0.8` pixels :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();
foreach (Point p in blackPixels) {

   if (rnd.Next(100) < 80) {
     // turn p to white
   }

}
```

For each element in the list it generates a number between 0 and 99, which means that 80% of the time the number will be between 0 and 79. This way you turn 80% of the pixels to white.

If you want to change *exactly* 80% of the pixels, you can go the other way around:

```
var numberOfPixelsToTurn = blackPixels.Count * 0.8
var rand = new Random();

for (int i; i < numberOfPixelsToTurn ; i++) {
  int itemToTurn = rand.Next(blackPixels.Count);
  TurnToWhite(blackPixels[itemToTurn]);
  blackPixels.RemoveAt(itemToTurn);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this function actually confused me as each time random creates an integer between 0 to 99 and it checks whether is lees than 80 or not. does that mean it turns 80 percent of the total black pixels to white?

Comment: Is turning each point to white with a probability of 80% the same as turning 80% of the points to white? I'd say it´s close but can be different.

Comment: I added an option if you want to change _exactly_ 80% of the pixels

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Iterate over each pixel. Call the Random.[Next(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to generate a random integer between 0 and 100. If the random number is less than 80 (yielding an 80% chance), change the pixel to white.

Comment: This is a good solution if he wants a random 80% white. Unfortunately, he didn't tell us if he wants random or linear.

Comment: @crush Sure he did, read the question again. "... can randomly change the colour ..."

Comment: Doh. Thanks. Not sure how I overlooked that. I vote for this answer because it tells him how to do it, explaining the theory, but doesn't do it for him.

Answer (score -1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();    
for(int x=0;x<blackPixels.Length;x++){

    int randomNumber = rnd.next(100);
    if(randomNumber <= 80){

         blackPixels[x] = // add a white pixel
    }

}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: -1: don't create a new Random() every time through the loop; doesn't show how to get an 80% probability using random numbers. (-1 removed since post was edited)

Comment: As you probably understood, I just pressed my enter prematurely